# Gradle sync failed... ERROR: Failed to resolve

Tags: android

I try to build a new project in android studio 3.4.2.

But I had the following errors:

CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL in 18s

ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0
Install Repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.test:runner:1.2.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue

1. On header menu got to ->Files
2. Then Click On invalid cache/Restart

Comment: Thank you, But it isn't work for me. I just changed order repository in module gradle ->(google() jcenter()) to (jcenter()   google()).  :\